# Using RJSONIO with R 2.13 Win7 (64-bit)?

Tags: r, windows-7, 64-bit, cran

I am having trouble installing RJSONIO for R version 2.13.0 I can manually download the binary and install it, but I can't use the library because it is "not installed for 'arch=x64'"

There is a similar question here: [Trouble installing RJSONIO library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036498/trouble-installing-rjsonio-library)

And the response referenced " building it from source" using RTools. I tried to download the program, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Can anyone explain how to resolve this issue? Would it be easier to just install a previous verion of R? For reference my OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The binaries provided on CRAN are for the 32-bit version of R for Windows.  This version works on 64-bit versions of Windows, so if downloading libraries is your preferred method of package install, then the easiest fix is to install 32-bit R.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any drawback to using 32-bit vs. 64?